# Replace enter char and tab char with HTML Code

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, string

```
 - Doza zilnica recomandata contine:
        Vitamina C (acid asorbic)   180,00 mg
        Vitamina E (D-Tocoferol)    45,00 mg
        Gluconat de zinc    140,00 mg (corespunde la 20 mg Zn)
        Gluconat de cupru   28,30 mg (corespunde la 4 mg Cu)
        Vitamina B6 (clorhidrat de piridoxina)  6,00 mg
```

I have a field in my table which is a text and looks like above . Now I want to convert the enter and tab char into a html code so It will look like this .

```
<table>    - Doza zilnica recomandata contine:
 <tr><td>Vitamina C (acid asorbic)</td><td>180,00 mg</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Vitamina E (D-Tocoferol)</td><td>45,00 mg</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Gluconat de zinc</td><td>140,00 mg (corespunde la 20 mg Zn)</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Gluconat de cupru</td><td>28,30 mg (corespunde la 4 mg Cu)</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Vitamina B6 (clorhidrat de piridoxina)</td><td>6,00 mg</td></tr>
</table>
```

The idea is that i have to replace char(10) and char(9) with the HTML code.

What I've done so far

```
SELECT '<table>'+REPLACE(REPLACE('- Doza zilnica recomandata contine:
Vitamina C (acid asorbic)   180,00 mg
Vitamina E (D-Tocoferol)    45,00 mg
Gluconat de zinc    140,00 mg (corespunde la 20 mg Zn)
Gluconat de cupru   28,30 mg (corespunde la 4 mg Cu)
Vitamina B6 (clorhidrat de piridoxina)  6,00 mg',char(9),'</td><td>'),char(10),'</td></tr><tr><td>')+ '</td></tr></table>'
```

Which is great but now I have to remove

Result :

```
<table>- Doza zilnica recomandata contine:
</td></tr><tr><td>Vitamina C (acid asorbic)</td><td>180,00 mg
</td></tr><tr><td>Vitamina E (D-Tocoferol)</td><td>45,00 mg
</td></tr><tr><td>Gluconat de zinc</td><td>140,00 mg (corespunde la 20 mg Zn)
</td></tr><tr><td>Gluconat de cupru</td><td>28,30 mg (corespunde la 4 mg Cu)
</td></tr><tr><td>Vitamina B6 (clorhidrat de piridoxina)</td><td>6,00 mg</td></tr></table>
```

How can I remove the first occurance of `</td></tr>` ?

Comment: Please, please, please - ***DON'T*** format HTML in SQL. Presentation is the responsibility of the application, not the database. Just select the data and do the postprocessing in PHP, Java, C# or whatever you're using.

Comment: It's what the client asked, I must do it like this.

Comment: And if he tells you to jump off a cliff...? The client is [not always right](http://notalwaysright.com/), otherwise he wouldn't hire you, a technical professional, to solve his problems. Doing this in SQL is ridiculous, a glaring example of code obfuscation to the point of making it unmaintainable and unreadable. It's your responsibility as a technical expert to intervene when clients want something stupid done. It's less code, faster and cleaner to do this where it should be done.

Comment: No, but I have to export this part of code with HTML from the DB. I don't think anyone would enjoy adding table codes for over 100.000 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `CHARINDEX (string_expression, target_expression [, start_location ])` would be useful.

Finds the first occurence of `target_expression` in `string_expression`.

Comment: I found my solution, using charindex. Thank you